# PHP echo results in new table, not new row

Tags: php, html

Currently the below puts everything into rows, I am wondering if there is a way to put these as individual tables every time instead of rows?

I am used to echo everything to rows as everything I have dealt with so far, is perfectly fine. But now I am at a point where it would be better to show all as individual tables.

I might not be explaining myself very well, sorry if not.

```
<table width="75%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="table">
          <tr align="center">
            <td class="header"><center>Patch Version</center></td>
            <td class="header"><center>Patch Date</center></td>
            <td class="header"><center>Update By</center></td>
            <?php if ($userlvl >= 3) { ?><td class="header"><center>Admin Settings</center></td></tr> <?php } else { } ?>
          </tr>
          <? 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE del ='0' ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    ?>
          <tr>


        </label></td>
            <td class="header"><center><h4><? echo $row['patchversion'] ?></h3></center></td>
            <td class="header"><center><h3><? echo $row['updatetime'] ?></h3></center></td>
            <td class="header"><center><h4><? echo $row['addedby']?></h4></td>
            <?php if ($userlvl >= 3) { ?><td class="header"><center><h4> <?php } else { } ?>
            <?php if ($userlvl >= 3){ echo "<a href=\"ChangeLog_Edit.php?action=edit&id=". $row['id'] ."\" onFocus=\"if(this.blur)this.blur()\">( Edit )</a>" ." - ". "<a href=\"ChangeLog.php?delete=". $row['id'] ."\" onFocus=\"if(this.blur)this.blur()\">( X )</a>"; } else { } ?></center></td>
            <tr><td class="cell" colspan="50"><? echo $row['news']?></td>
          </tr>
            <?php }
           ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: The while loop will execute every time the condition is true. So as long as you have results to show it will continue to loop. Briefly, you should put the code of the table inside your `while-loop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the table tags within your while loop, something like this for example:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
?>
       <table>

           <tr>
            <td class="header"><center><h4><? echo $row['patchversion'] ?></h3></center></td>
            <td class="header"><center><h3><? echo $row['updatetime'] ?></h3></center></td>
            <td class="header"><center><h4><? echo $row['addedby']?></h4></td>
            <?php if ($userlvl >= 3) { ?><td class="header"><center><h4> <?php } else { } ?>
            <?php if ($userlvl >= 3){ echo "<a href=\"ChangeLog_Edit.php?action=edit&id=". $row['id'] ."\" onFocus=\"if(this.blur)this.blur()\">( Edit )</a>" ." - ". "<a href=\"ChangeLog.php?delete=". $row['id'] ."\" onFocus=\"if(this.blur)this.blur()\">( X )</a>"; } else { } ?></center></td>

          </tr>

     </table>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks, that has sort of worked. It has threw out alot of my layout, but nothing that cannot be changed with any other width / hight fixes